# iOS interfaceBuilder - attributedText how to add subscript typeface

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

in xcode's interfacebuilder when i switch a uilabel from text to attributedText how do i add subscript or superscript to the typeface section ? I'd like to change some text on the fly .  Here is an image to show what i need done in interfacebuilder:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set many attributes via Interface Builder, but I think that this is one that you can do only in code. What you have to do is add a value for the `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` attribute, which takes a floating-point value to indicate the *y* offset from the font's baseline.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply styling to an attributedText in interfacebuilder, then te easiest way would be by creating a custom UILabel subclass with extra properties. You could use the AttributedTextView library for easy configuration of the attributedText from code. For a sample see:
https://github.com/evermeer/AttributedTextView#creating-your-own-custom-label